# Deregister CSS style link 'open-sans-css'

Tags: css, admin-bar, wp-head, admin-css

When user is logged in WP add in its footer this CSS:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans....' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

That style is not registered inside my theme, if I change my theme I still have that file called in any theme, it is somewhere inside WP core files.

How to remove it?

Comment: it is probably one of your plugins

Comment: I deactivated all my plugins and checked again, and it is still in use. Like @Caleb said it's not a plugin.

Comment: In 2017 it is in Jetpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP Core actually uses Open Sans font; it's not a plugin. there is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-open-sans-font-from-wp-core/) that removes it, but you can probably simply [dequeue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) or [deregister](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style) it.

adding this to functions.php should work; if you want it removed from the backend as well, hook into the `admin_print_styles` action.

```
function dequeue_opensans_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'open-sans' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_opensans_css', 999 );
```

if it's in the footer, change the `add_action()` line:

`add_action('wp_footer','dequeue _opensans_css',1);`

untested, but that should work.

Comment: Cold you please provide me more informations about how exactly I should dequeue or deregister it?

Comment: edited answer with example.

Comment: I tried your code, and it does not work I still have that open-sans-css linked. But, I had one more css linked from one my plugin and I successfully removed it using same pattern you provided. Why than it is not working for WP Core CSS?

Comment: is the code appearing in the head tags, or is it towards the bottom?

Comment: It is at the bottom, in wp_footer section.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your functions.php

```
function replace_admin_open_sans() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'open-sans' );
    wp_register_style( 'open-sans', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'open-sans', '' );
}
add_action( 'init', replace_admin_open_sans');
```